# Bootstrap nav bar drop down element

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've generated a bootstrap 3 nav bar, and it works perfectly apart from one use case that I cant quite figure out.

When I open a drop down menu the nav bar element goes to a black color, even though I haven't defined this behavior.

When I inspect the element, I can see that the following CSS seems to be followed (I changed the colours for proof this is the offending item), although I thought this was over written in my CSS style:

```
.navbar-nav>.open>a {
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,#080808 0,#0f0f0f 100%);
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top,#080808 0,#0f0f0f 100%);
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear,left top,left   bottom,from(#080808),to(#0f0f0f));
background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom,#FFFFFF 0,#FFFFFF 100%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ff080808', endColorstr='#ff0f0f0f', GradientType=0);
background-repeat: repeat-x;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 3px 9px rgba(0,0,0,.25);
box-shadow: inset 0 3px 9px rgba(0,0,0,.25);
}
```

How do I remove this style so that my background colour of the navbar element stays in the colour that I want it to be?

My HTML:

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">           
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">My brand here</a>
        </div>           
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li>
                    <a href="index.html">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Item One</a>
                </li>
                 <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">Item Two <b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Drop down item </a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Drop down item </a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Drop down item </a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Drop down item </a></li>                                                       
                    </ul>
                </li>
                 <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">Item three <b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Drop down item </a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Drop down item </a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Drop down item </a></li>                                                       
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Item four </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Item five</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->
</nav>
```

My CSS styles for the nav bar

```
 .navbar-inverse { background-color: #F61E99}
    .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover,.navbar-inverse .navbar-  nav>li>a:hover, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a:focus { background-color: #FFFFFF}
    .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.active>a,.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.open>a,.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.open>a, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.open>a:hover,.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.open>a, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.open>a:hover, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.open>a:focus { background-color: #F61E99}
.dropdown-menu { background-color: #FFFFFF}
.dropdown-menu .open {background-color: #F61E99}
.dropdown-menu>li>a:hover, .dropdown-menu>li>a:focus { background-color: #F61E99}
.navbar-inverse { background-image: none; }
.dropdown-menu>li>a:hover, .dropdown-menu>li>a:focus { background-image: none; }
.navbar-inverse { border-color: #F61E99}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-brand { color: #FFFFFF}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-brand:hover { color: #FFFFFF}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a { color: #FFFFFF}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a:hover, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a:focus { color: #F61E99}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.active>a,.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.open>a, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.open>a:hover, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.open>a:focus { color: #FFFFFF}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.active>a:focus { color: #FFFFFF}
.dropdown-menu>li>a { color: #333333}
.dropdown-menu>li>a:hover, .dropdown-menu>li>a:focus { color: #FFFFFF}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.dropdown>a .caret { border-top-color: #999999}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.dropdown>a:hover .caret { border-top-color: #FFFFFF}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.dropdown>a .caret { border-bottom-color: #999999}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.dropdown>a:hover .caret { border-bottom-color: #FFFFFF}
```

My screenshot of the behavior when I open the navbar drop down:
[image]

Comment: can you put it in a fiddle as most people don't have the time to copy and paste all your code to test it. thanks

Comment: @blairmeister sure doing now.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ffjpdnor/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overwrite the `background-image` property for the `nav-bar`. Update your CSS code like below.

```
  .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.active>a,.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.open>a,.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.open>a, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.open>a:hover,.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.open>a, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.open>a:hover, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.open>a:focus {background-image:none !important; background-color: #F61E99 !important;}
```